# Second Monday of Current year

Tags: java

I need to calculate second monday of current year in one of program.  a method in java which tells what is the date on second monday of current year using Gregorian Calendar. Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could try using the `Calendar` class and setting the month to January (since it's definitely the 2nd monday of the year will be in Jan), and getting the Date of the first day of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear() )
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 2 , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
             .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Avoid the old legacy date-time classes as they are poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for classes to manipulate date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note plural 's') class provides several handy implementations.

We an adjuster to get the first day of the current year, and another to get the second Monday of that month.

```
LocalDate firstOfYear = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear() );
LocalDate secondMondayOfYear = firstOfYear.with( TemporalAdjuster.dayOfWeekInMonth( 2 , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
```

## `GregorianCalendar`

If you really need a `GregorianCalendar` you can convert by calling new methods added to the old classes. I assume you want the time-of-day set to the first moment of the day. That first moment is *not* always `00:00:00` so let java.time determine that time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = secondMondayOfYear.atStartOfDay( z );
GregorianCalendar gc = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( zdt );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could have written something like this

```
int year = 2016;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 2);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
return cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WEEK_OF_MONTH` instead of `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` being set to 2 to set it to the 2nd week's Monday in January 2016?

Comment: if the first week of the month does not start on a monday, using `WEEK_OF_MONTH` set to 2 will still give the first monday of the month.

Comment: Oh you're right. Got confused right there...

Answer (score 1):

Set calendar to the first day of the month jan.

Retrieve its day of the week

Calculate the date of the first Monday of the month.

Add 7 days using calendar.add() method. You will get the second Monday.

Comment: Not always correct.  There are week numbering systems that can start week 1 prior to Jan 1st.